Find value in sheet1, copy offset value, find offset value in sheet 2, paste text in offset cell
I have looked at a lot of different ways to do this and tried to incorporate their ideas into this sub but I keep getting different errors every time I run it. I am searching for "0" in the listed ranges of the STATUS SHEET and finding the offset value which is the vehicle number. Then finding that vehicle number on LRV ISSUES and pasting "OOS" one cell to the right. It seems to work once and then errors so I am thinking my looping is wrong.
Thanks for any help.
EDIT TO INCLUDE SUGGESTIONS AND CLEAN UP
Sub FindOOS()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstAddressC As String
    Dim firstAddressD As String
    Dim lrv As String
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STATUS SHEET")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LRV ISSUES")
    
    With sht1.Range("B5:B37,E5:E37,H5:H37,K5:K37,M5:M35")
        Set c = .Find("0", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddressC = c.Address
            Do
                lrv = c.Offset(, -1).Value
                With sht2.Range("A3:R32")
                    Set d = .Find(lrv, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not d Is Nothing Then
                        d.Offset(, 1).Value = "OOS"
                    End If
                End With
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddressC
        End If
    End With
End Sub

STATUS SHEET MD



101
1

134
1

167
0
SHOP/NWROF
200
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
233
2N
PMI NW NIS 1R




102
3
NIS
135
0
SHOP
168
0
SHOP/NWROF
201
1

234
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN


103
1

136
2C
BODY SHOP
169
2N
OOS/NW/NO RUN/WHEELS
202
1

235
2C
Gear Box


104
1R
A coupled restriction/TSS
137
0
SHOP
170
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN/THRESHOLD
203
0
SHOP
236
1



105
3
NIS
138
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
171
1

204
2C
PMI CROF
237
1



106
3
NIS
139
0
SHOP
172
0
SHOP
205
2C
PMI CROF
238
1
WHEELS


107
3
NIS
140
0
SHOP
173
1
WHEELS
206
1

239
1



108
0R
SHOP/A COUPLED
141
1

174
2N
PMI NW
207
0
SHOP
240
2N
NIS/NW


109
0R
A COUPLED/B shear bolt/SHOP
142
1

175
2N
NIS/NW
208
2R
A COUPLED/TIRE X-CHANGE
241
1



110
1

143
0
SHOP
176
1

209
1

242
2C
TIRE X-CHANGE


111
1

144
1

177
3
Engineering
210
2C
PMI CROF
243
2N
TRANSPORTATION DOWNLOAD


112
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
145
1

178
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN/WHEELS
211
1

244
1



113
2N
PMI NW
146
1

179
2C
SHOP
212
1

245
1



114
1

147
1

180
2R
B COUPLED/RCS BODY SHOP
213
2C
PMI CROF
246
1



115
1

148
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
181
1

214
1

247
1



116
1

149
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN /shop
182
1

215
1

248
1



117
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
150
2C
PMI CROF
183
1

216
1

249
1



118
1

151
0
SHOP/NWROF
184
1

217
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
250
1



119
1

152
0
SHOP
185
1

218
2N
OOS/NW/NO RUN
251
1
WHEELS


120
1

153
1

186
1

219
1

252
0
SHOP


121
1
WHEELS
154
2C
BODY SHOP
187
2C
RCS/AIRLINE
220
1

253
2N
OOS/NW/NO RUN


122
1

155
1

188
1

221
2N
PMI NW
254
1



123
1

156
1

189
1

222
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
255
1



124
2C
Air spring
157
3
NIS
190
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN/Body shop
223
0
SHOP
256
0
SHOP


125
1

158
1

191
0
SHOP/NWROF
224
1

257
1



126
0
SHOP
159
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN/SHOP
192
1

225
1

258
1



127
1

160
1

193
1

226
3
NIS
259
1



128
1

161
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
194
0
SHOP/NWROF
227
0
SHOP
260
1
NIS/ 4L motor


129
2C
RCS/Axle 2, Wire short
162
2C
PMI CROF
195
2N
BODY SHOP/SHOP
228
1

261
1



130
0
SHOP
163
1

196
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
229
0R
SHOP/A COUPLED/Radio
262
1



131
1

164
0
SHOP
197
0
SHOP
230
1

263
1



132
1

165
1

198
1

231
1
WHEELS
STREET CAR




133
2C
OOS/CROF/NO RUN
166
0
SHOP
199
1R
B COUPLED
232
1







LRV ISSUES MD



LRV
DATE
CAMS
LRV
DATE
CAMS
LRV
DATE
CAMS
LRV
DATE
CAMS
LRV
DATE
CAMS
LRV
DATE
CAMS




101
45420
Ø
131
45417
Ø M5
161
45384
Ø
191
45420
Ø
221
45418
11
251
45397
SAT


102
NIS
NIS
132

SAT
162
45413
6 10 11
192
45390
Ø
222
45406
Ø
252
45415
Ø


103
45419
D5
133
45384
Ø
163
45417
Ø
193
45413
SAT
223
45415
Ø
253
45399
8 9 CUT7


104
45417
SAT
134
45418
Ø
164
45378
Ø
194
45420
Ø
224
45418
Ø
254
45415
SAT


105
NIS
NIS
135
45407
Ø
165
45417
5
195
45415
Ø
225
45392
*NOTE
255
45403
H2O 6


106
NIS
NIS
136
45399
Ø
166
45398
Ø
196
45419
Ø
226
NIS
NIS
256
45406
7 10


107
NIS
NIS
137
45393
Ø
167
45417
Ø
197
45415
Ø
227
45406
8 9 11
257
45420
Ø


108

SAT
138
45418
Ø
168
45415
Ø
198
45419
Ø
228
45397
Ø
258
45411
Ø


109
45417
SAT
139
45392
Ø
169
45418
Ø
199
45415
Ø
229
45420
Ø
259
45415
Ø


110
45417
10
140
45393
SAT
170
45403
Ø
200
45418
Ø
230
45415
Ø
260
45415
Ø M2


111
45413
Ø
141
45386
Ø
171
45417
3
201
45419
Ø
231
45406
3
261
45417
7 10 D4 D8


112
45371
Ø
142
45419
Ø
172
45413
SAT
202
45420
Ø
232
45417
Ø
262
45417
M3


113
45417
2
143
45418
Ø
173
45411
Ø
203
45420
Ø
233
45420
Ø
263
45417
Ø


114
45386
7
144
45417
Ø
174
45418
6 D9
204
45419
Ø
234
45415
Ø





115
45420
Ø
145
45415
Ø
175
45389
Ø
205
45413
Ø
235
45399
Ø





116
45420
Ø
146
45420
Ø
176
45420
Ø
206
45420
4
236
45406






117
45413
9
147
45413
1 3
177
NIS
NIS
207
45406
4 7 11
237
45420
Ø





118
45406
Ø
148
45392
5 D9
178
45392
Ø
208
45344
SAT
238
45420
6 7





119
45418
Ø
149
45370
Ø
179
45399
Ø
209
45417
Ø
239
45419
Ø





120
45393
SAT
150
45419
SAT
180
45367
Ø
210
45393
Ø M10
240
45415
Ø





121
45418
SAT
151
45393
Ø
181
45418
Ø
211
45406
Ø
241
45403
Ø





122
45413
Ø
152
45390
Ø
182
45420
SAT
212
45417
1-7 D10
242
45385
Ø





123
45407
11
153
45415
Ø
183
45417
3
213
45413
SAT
243
45406
D2





124
45390
Ø
154
45391
Ø
184
45420
Ø
214
45415
Ø M5
244
45420
Ø





125
45386
SAT
155
45370
4
185
45408
Ø
215
45406
Ø
245
45392
Ø





126
45417
Ø
156
45420
Ø
186
45415
Ø
216
45385
Ø
246
45417
Ø





127
45415
Ø
157
NIS
NIS
187
45389
Ø
217
45397
Ø
247
45417
Ø





128
45419
2 6 9
158
45411
Ø
188
45405
3 8 11
218
45400
Ø
248
45419
Ø





129
45407
4 5 D10
159
45398
Ø
189
45413
2 6
219
45420
Ø
249
45419
Ø





130
45415
Ø
160
45418
Ø
190
45419
Ø
220
45413
7 9
250
45419
*NOTE







Wouldn't "OOS" paste over top of the "DATE" column in LRV ISSUES?

That is fine. I clear the OOS before I run this macro so if an LRV is back in service, the date will be blank and signal I should check it.


It's better to specify the argument LookAt:=xlWhole (assuming you are looking for whole cell matching) in Find method.

finding the offset value which is the vehicle number - Use the below code to store the vehicle number in a variable (lrv).


lrv = c.Offset(, -1).Value


Set d = .Find(lrv, LookIn:=xlValues) in your code searched lrv on sheet STATUS SHEET. You need another With.

Loop While c.Address <> firstAddressC The condition is necessary to avoid looping search.


Option Explicit
Sub FindOOS()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim firstAddressC As String
    Dim firstAddressD As String
    Dim lrv As String
    
    With Worksheets("STATUS SHEET").Range("B5:B37,E5:E37,H5:H37,K5:K37,M5:M35")
        Set c = .Find("0", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddressC = c.Address
            Do
                lrv = c.Offset(, -1).Value  ' **
                With Worksheets("LRV ISSUES").Range("A3:R32")
                    Set d = .Find(lrv, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not d Is Nothing Then
                        d.Offset(, 1).Value = "OOS"
                    End If
                End With
                Set c = .Find("0", After:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
'                Debug.Print c.Address
            Loop While c.Address <> firstAddressC
        End If
    End With
End Sub

btw, it's worth to read.
How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

I am getting an error 91, object variable or with block variable not set.

Which line raises the error?

Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddressC

That works, once. I had the same issue and was trying to fix it. It finds the first instance of a "0" in the range and finds/inserts "OOC" correctly but stops looping.

Please edit your post to share the sample data.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

The MD table formatted strangely so I inserted a screen capture

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
The data on both sheets are necessary for testing.

Sorry about that. Done.

Try the updated code. FindNext tries to repeat the closest search (ie, the 2nd Find on LRV ISSUES). That's the reason why it only successfully replaced the first matching record.

That worked except for the .select. I removed that and changed the xlWhole to xlPart and it found what I needed. Thanks so much for your help.

Select is for testing. It is not necessary.
